# Tree shaking in namespace module

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, tree-shaking

There is a module that is used as a namespace (for testability reasons or else):

```
export function bar() {}

export function baz() {
    this.bar();
}

export function qux() {}
```

This can be considered a bad practice because `baz` depends on the context and cannot be imported alone as named export:

```
import * as Foo from './foo';
Foo.baz();
```

Is it safe to assume that `this.bar` doesn't affect tree shaking mechanism, and `bar` and `qux` will be tree-shaken?

Is it possible to make a bundler to be aware of a relation between `bar` and `baz`, so if `Foo.baz` is in use, only `qux` is tree-shaken?

The question primarily addresses Webpack tree shaking, but an explanation for other bundlers (Rollup) is also welcome.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bad practice. I don't know how it affects tree shaking, but to fix it (and make the bundler aware of the dependency) just refer to `bar()`.